# Nonewline messes up output for Powershell

Tags: powershell, newline, space

This is a continuation from my previous question. I followed some advice on how to color parts of words but now that I have this format with "nonewline" the listings of the Managing Groups now all go in one line versus their own.

In other words it prints like so:

Managing Group: .... Descripton: .... Managing Groups: .... Description: ....

I've tried playing with the newline in various positions but I don't want a large empty space between each Managing Group one user controls. I just want the listing as followed:

**Managing Group: ... Description: ...**

(nobreak)

**Managing Group: ... Description: ...**

Can you explain why the new line option isn't working and what process I should go about it?

```
if ($owned -eq $Null){
$owned | % {write-host "Managing Group: " -nonewline}
$owned | % {write-host "None Found " -foreground red -nonewline}
$owned | % {write-host "Group Description: " -nonewline}
$owned | % {write-host "None Provided " -foreground red }
write-host "`n"
}

elseif ($description -eq $Null){
$owned | % {write-host ("Managing Group: " + $_.name + "Group Description: ") -nonewline}
$owned | % {write-host "None Provided " -foreground red}
write-host "`n"

}
else {
$owned | % {write-host ("Managing Group: " + $_.name + "Group Description: " + $_.description -   replace "`r`n", "  ")}
Write-host "`n"
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the lines containing `write-host "\`n"`?

Comment: They print the same way aka: Managing Group..Description..Managing Group..Description in one line.

Comment: Before I changed my format to use "nonewline" to get the foreground color they were printing correctly

Comment: initially i just had code like: $owned | % {write-host "Managing Group: None Found" "Group Description: None Provided"} and it was fine but i didn't get the red coloring I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you are saying the gap is too important between two sets of Managing Groups.
I think the issues comes from using

```
write-host "`n"
```

Write-host already issues a newline, and

```
"`n"
```

is a second newline, hence the large break.

In your first code block following the if (which I'd write like this as $owned is assumed to be $null so piping it to a foreach won't really do much other than piping a $null once):

```
if ($owned -eq $Null){
    write-host "Managing Group: " -nonewline
    write-host "None Found " -foreground red -nonewline
    write-host "Group Description: " -nonewline
    write-host "None Provided " -foreground red 
}
```

the last `write-host` does not have the `-nonewline` parameter, so there will be a newline added.

If repeated just to check the output will be:

```
Managing Group: None Found Group Description: None Provided 
Managing Group: None Found Group Description: None Provided
```

The same idea needs to be applied to the other code blocks following the elseif and else.

**Update**

This might help fix the second part of the code:

```
elseif ($description -eq $Null){
    $owned | % {
        write-host ("Managing Group: " + $_.name + " Group Description: ") -nonewline
        write-host "None Provided " -foreground red
        }
}
else {
    $owned | % {write-host ("Managing Group: " + $_.name + " Group Description: " + $_.description -   replace "`r`n", "  ")}
}
```

Comment: The Write-host "'n" made no changes by how it was displayed in my code above. I tried also changing it to look like yours by removing my "$owned | %" but now nothing (groups) print.

Comment: I meant the `"$owned | %"` should be removed only in the first if, not everywhere.

Comment: Oh ok I see what you mean now. I removed that but i still see issues. For example in one row i get: Managing Group: BU_CS_PSBA_COLLCORRGroup Description: Managing Group: BU_CS_PAYISSUESGroup Description: None Provided 
None Provided 

what makes this one so off is also by the double "None Provided" at the end where the first group is missing it's "None Provided" which tells me that it skipped and print at the end??? makes no sense

Comment: I updated the answer with the second part of the code (the elseif, and the else). See if this improves the output.

Comment: Thank you. So close to what I actually had before XD. The updated version worked. Just a few logic fixes I need to do but the printing is correct. I really appreciate your help